# Solving the equation system $\{x+z=-6,y+zx=-1,yz=30\}$?

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I am interested in solving the following system of non-linear equations.

I am looking for $$x,y,z \in \mathbb{C}$$  with

$$x+z = -6$$
$$y+zx=-1$$
$$yz=30$$

In fact I am actually interested in just establishing a solution exists even without finding it. Also the constants on the right side are somewhat arbitrary so I would like an argument that can apply for any numbers there.  I also realize I could do a direct substitution which could reduce this to solving a single cubic equation but that is not ideal because it would then rest on me being able to solve an arbitrary cubic if I let the constants be arbitrary.

Is there some sort of concept, analogous to determinants for linear systems, that would help here?

Comment: "*just establishing a solution exists*" $\;$ A cubic always has at least one root in $\mathbb R$ and exactly three roots in $\mathbb C$ (counting multiplicities), which  establishes the existence in all cases.

Comment: Right, but the point was I was trying to come up with a pure algebraic proof that a cubic can be factored into a linear and a quadratic.    The x,y,z were representing the unknown coefficients of the quadratic and the linear.  It appears this is a dead end though.

Answer (score 3):

Let us consider the following system of nonlinear equations:
$$x+z=\alpha,\ y+zx=\beta,\ yz=\gamma.$$

If $\gamma=0$, then either $z=0$ or $y=0$. In the first case, we then have that $x=\alpha$ and $y=\beta$. In the second case, we have the expressions $x+z=\alpha$ and $zx=\beta$ which means that $x$ and $z$ are the two roots of the quadratic polynomial $p(s)=s^2-\alpha s+\beta$.

Now consider the case that $\gamma\ne0$. In this case, we have that $z\ne0$ as well. If we multiply by $z$ the two first expressions we get that

$$z(x+z)=zx+z^2=z\alpha,\quad z(y+zx)=zy+z^2=\beta z.$$

Combining those expressions together with $yz=\gamma$ yields the following cubic polynomial equation $q(z)=0$ where

$$q(z)=-z^3+\alpha z^2-\beta z+\gamma.$$

This equation has three solutions in $\mathbb{C}$ which we denote by $z_1,z_2,z_3$. So, we have three solutions $(x,y,z)=(\alpha-z_i,\gamma/z_i,z_i)$, $i=1,2,3$.

To summarize:

- If $\gamma=0$, the solutions are $(\alpha,\beta,0)$, $(s_1,0,s_2)$, and $(s_2,0,s_1)$ where $s_1$ and $s_2$ are the two roots of the polynomial $p(s)$.
- If $\gamma\ne0$, the solutions are $(\alpha-z_i,\gamma/z_i,z_i)$, $i=1,2,3$, where $z_i$ are the roots of $q(z)$.

Comment: I think you're missing a "not equals" in your last summary point

"If γ=/=0, the solutions are (α−zi,γ/zi,zi), i=1,2,3, where zi are the roots of q(z)."

Comment: Thanks for your work here but it kind of defeated my goal,  because really I set up this system in an attempt to find a way to solve the cubic you identified hoping that there would be some method of solving the system that didn't just reduce back to solving the cubic i started with.  Basically the x,y,z were representing the coefficients of the quadratic and the linear binomial which I was trying to factor the cubic into.

Comment: @Elliot Then, you should ask the real question next time. Check this out https://xyproblem.info/ and avoid it next time. Moreover, cubic equations have explicit solutions even though they can be quite complicated.

Comment: @BrianJ That's correct. I am fixing this.

Comment: @KBS sorry if you are annoyed for having your time wasted, I was simply exploring an idea that I had hoping that there may be tools which could be applied to such a system that I was unaware of already

Comment: @Elliot I am not annoyed as it was a fun exercise but if you want an answer to a question, ask the question directly and not another one.

Comment: @KBS  so I originally approached this from the mindset of trying to basically prove the fundamental theorem of algebra because I figured out how to construct a system similar to this one which a solution would essentially represent a factorization of a polynomial.  It seems this will not work because the way we solve that system just boils down to the cubic again, BUT what about in the reverse direction?  Maybe by understanding how exactly these systems correspond with polynom. we might be able to take more general systems and use our knowledge of how to find roots to help solve the system

Comment: @Elliot Roots of polynomials have been extensively studied. We have a lot of methods for them from Galois Theory to algebraic geometry. Moreover, the fundamental theorem of algebra pertains to univariate of polynomials which are much simpler than systems of polynomials in several variables. If you want you can use algebraic geometry methods for analyzing your system of polynomials in 3 variables, but you will likely end up to the same point.

Comment: @KBS  Thanks again for help, one final question:  can every system of polynomial equations be reduced to finding roots of a univariate polynomial by way of substitution?

It is clear to me that the systems I am looking at CAN always be done that way (I built them that way) but I am wondering if there are other systems that would not be possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135872/discussion-between-kbs-and-elliot).

Comment: @Elliot This is a very good question. My guess is no. For instance, you can have two polynomial equations $p(z)$=0 and $xyz=0$. So, it will not be possible to have a unique polynomial to solve here. This looks like a silly example but, in fact, you can generate from it as many systems through bijective changes of variables of the form $(x,y,z)=F(u,v,w)$ for some other variables $(u,v,w)$. None of them will be reducible to a polynomial in one variable. Such a problem should have been addressed in the literature on algebraic geometry. I would suggest you to ask a separate question here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a, b , c \in {\Bbb C}$ with $c \not= 0$. The system
\begin{align}
x+z &= a \\
y + zx &= b \\
yz &= -c
\end{align}
is equivalent to $x = -z - a$, $y = -c/z$ and
$zy + z^2x - bz = 0$ and this latter equation can be rewritten as $z^2(-z-a)-bz -c = 0$, that is $z^3 + az^2 + bz + c = 0$.

In other words, a suitable choice of the right hand side of your equations yields a generic cubic equation, so your problem is essentially equivalent to solving a cubic equation. If you just want to prove the existence of a solution, then of course every polynomial equation in $\Bbb C$ has a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your work here but it kind of defeated my goal,  because really I set up this system in an attempt to find a way to solve the cubic you identified hoping that there would be some method of solving the system that didn't just reduce back to solving the cubic i started with.  Basically the x,y,z were representing the coefficients of the quadratic and the linear binomial which I was trying to factor the cubic into.